# Question about a double summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose you have two arbitrary sequences of real numbers, say $\{ \gamma_n \}$ and $\{ c_{n,m} \}$. Suppose also that $c_{n,m}$ is not identically 0 for all pairs $(m,n)$, and also that for fixed $n$, $\sum_{m=0}^n c_{n,m} \neq 0$.

If

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \gamma_n c_{n,m}  = 0$$

Does it necessarily follow that $\gamma_n = 0$ for all $n$?

My intuition tells me yes but I do not know how to prove it, and it is also entirely possible that it is not actually true. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is negative.  Consider the case where
$$ c_{n,m}=1 \qquad (n,m\geq0), $$
$$ \gamma_0=-1,\qquad \gamma_n=2^{-n} \qquad (n\geq 1). $$
Then, for fixed $m$, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\gamma_nc_{n,m}=-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}=0. $$
Then summing over $m$ is just a sum of infinitely many zeros, yielding zero.

Comment: Good example. Indeed this choice for $\gamma_n$ will always work for a constant sequence. What about nonconstant sequences?

Comment: That will require more work, given your condition that $\sum_{m=0}^n c_{n,m} \neq 0$ for fixed $n$.  But I still think one can find a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, I came across this condition while trying to prove a certain set of polynomials were a basis. The $c_{n,m}$ are in fact the $n$th Legendre Polynomial's coefficient of the term $x^m$ in my case, it is very counter intuitive.

Comment: Interesting! Now I see why you don't want constant sequences.